# Can't seem to use this function in the Boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I'm working on a program that uses the Boost regular expressions library, and I'm running into an issue where while trying to call the boost::regex_match() function, I'm getting a strange error that I've never encountered before. Here is the relevant code.

```
boost::regex pattern("REGEX REDACTED");
boost::cmatch what;

XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER cout << "Enter XML Document-Building Commands" << XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER endl;
while(true) {
    // Take the input from the user.
    std::string input;
    XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER cout << ">> ";
    XERCES_STD_QUALIFIER getline(in, input);

    if(boost::regex_match(input, what, pattern)) {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

This is almost exactly what I took out of example code from a similar program my instructor provided for this assignment. But when I try to compile, I get this error. If it helps, I'm using NetBeans 8.

```
XMLDoc.cpp: In member function ‘void XMLDoc::createDoc(std::istream&)’:
XMLDoc.cpp:164:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘regex_match(std::string&,     boost::cmatch&, boost::regex&)’
XMLDoc.cpp:164:51: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:145:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/regex.hpp:31,
                 from XMLDoc.cpp:13:
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:44:6: note: template<class BidiIterator, class Allocator, class charT, class traits> bool boost::regex_match(BidiIterator, BidiIterator, boost::match_results<Iterator, Allocator>&, const boost::basic_regex<charT, traits>&, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type)
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:44:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
XMLDoc.cpp:164:51: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘BidiIterator’ (‘std::basic_string<char>’ and ‘boost::match_results<const char*>’)
In file included from /usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:145:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/regex.hpp:31,
                 from XMLDoc.cpp:13:
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:53:6: note: template<class iterator, class charT, class traits> bool boost::regex_match(iterator, iterator, const boost::basic_regex<charT, traits>&, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type)
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:53:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
XMLDoc.cpp:164:51: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘iterator’ (‘std::basic_string<char>’ and ‘boost::match_results<const char*>’)
In file included from /usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:145:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/regex.hpp:31,
                 from XMLDoc.cpp:13:
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:68:13: note: template<class charT, class Allocator, class traits> bool boost::regex_match(const charT*, boost::match_results<const charT*, Allocator>&, const boost::basic_regex<charT, traits2>&, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type)
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:68:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
XMLDoc.cpp:164:51: note:   mismatched types ‘const charT*’ and ‘std::basic_string<char>’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:145:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/regex.hpp:31,
                 from XMLDoc.cpp:13:
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:77:13: note: bool boost::regex_match(const std::basic_string<charT, ST, SA>&, boost::match_results<typename std::basic_string<charT, ST, SA>::const_iterator, Allocator>&, const boost::basic_regex<charT, traits>&, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type) [with ST = std::char_traits<char>; SA = std::allocator<char>; Allocator = std::allocator<boost::sub_match<const char*> >; charT = char; traits = boost::regex_traits<char>; typename std::basic_string<charT, ST, SA>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >; boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type = boost::regex_constants::_match_flags]
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:77:13: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘boost::cmatch {aka boost::match_results<const char*>}’ to ‘boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<const char*> > >&’
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:85:13: note: template<class charT, class traits> bool boost::regex_match(const charT*, const boost::basic_regex<charT, traits>&, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type)
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:85:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
XMLDoc.cpp:164:51: note:   mismatched types ‘const charT*’ and ‘std::basic_string<char>’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:145:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/regex.hpp:31,
                 from XMLDoc.cpp:13:
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:94:13: note: template<class ST, class SA, class charT, class traits> bool boost::regex_match(const std::basic_string<charT, ST, SA>&, const boost::basic_regex<charT, traits>&, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type)
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:94:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
XMLDoc.cpp:164:51: note:   ‘boost::cmatch {aka boost::match_results<const char*>}’ is not derived from ‘const boost::basic_regex<charT, traits>’
```

Can someone help me out here? I'm certain I included the library properly because I have another project with the exact same Linker properties that uses the boost::regex_match function (minus the cmatch object parameter), and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use a `std::string` input, you have to use `boost::smatch` instead of `boost::cmatch`. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_results.html. So all you need to do is change

```
boost::cmatch what;
```

to

```
boost::smatch what;
```

Comment: I tried doing input.c_str() as well and got a similar error.

Comment: What was the error? I can do input.c_str() with boost::cmatch and it works for me.

Comment: I swapped it out for boost::smatch and got the same exact error.

Comment: If you got the same exact error as you copied in your original question, then you must still be using a std::string with a boost::cmatch, because it says in the error output `XMLDoc.cpp:164:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘regex_match(std::string&,     boost::cmatch&, boost::regex&)’`.

Comment: Ok, so not the SAME EXACT error, but here's something interesting... the only difference between the project that worked and this one is that this one is using the C++11 standard. I tried changing it to the default and it compiles now, but is now giving me an error with my regular expression. I know the expression is right, though, because I checked it on RegexPal.com and it correctly identified several strings I was testing against.